# Spring Jdbc template's update method not returning number of rows updated

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am facing this weird issue with spring Jdbc Template when used for Oracle DB.

JDK version- 11.0.3
ojdbc8 version- 12.2.0.1
Spring jdbc version-2.2.4.RELEASE
DB- Oracle- 12c

**Issue:**
When I call update() method on Jdbc Template, sometimes it does not return number of updated rows and returns '0' instead. 
When I run same code with in memory db such as H2, it goes smooth.
I checked queries very closely and they are looking fine.

Comment: Its hard to know without seeing more. Do you have a repeatable test that showcases the issue? It sounds like you are uncertain if this is really a bug or not.

Comment: Can you verify that the update which returns 0 actually changed values?

Comment: I wrote multiple tests using H2 db and its working fine. But when application connects to Oracle Db, it starts breaking. Data used in-between those test is also same.

Comment: Yes,  its really not getting updated but not sure on reason.

Comment: is your method marked @Transactional? If not, try using flush() on the entity after you call update(). I don't know about H2 but Oracle is a transactional DB, it won't write the updates to the database unless the transaction is complete.

Comment: yes, it will give virtual result as transaction will be rollbacked in case of exception. I think 'Char' data type is culprit here as its getting right padded in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the handling of the CHAR datatype in Oracle.
Oracle was doing right padding for this datatype and Jdbc query was failing for equality check cause of that(in SQL query 'WHERE' clause where I was using this field).
The use of RTRIM function in Query at the java side resolved this issue.